# Crop UIImage according to Image Resolution

Tags: ios

I have one `UIImageView`. Its content mode is set to `AspectFit`.

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit].
```

I need to crop a `subImage` from this image. This is the code which crops the image:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageView.image CGImage], customRect);
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

where `customRect` is the rectangle from which I need to crop the image.

This is how I calculate it:

```
CGRect customRect = CGRectMake((cropView.frame.origin.x/xFactor),
                               (cropView.frame.origin.y/yFactor),
                               (cropView.frame.size.width/xFactor),
                               (cropView.frame.size.height/yFactor));
```

The problem comes in cropping. `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` crops the given area according to the actual image size which, in some cases, is larger than the image view size. I tried using other approaches such as `UIGraphics:getImageFromCurrentImageContext` but these do not keep the image quality as much as it degrades them.

Comment: Try calculating the size of `customRect` by reversing the effect of the scaling of the `imageView`: calculate the X and Y scaling factor of the imageView and apply the reverse scaling on the `customRect` before cropping.

Comment: Hi Pieter- Can you please explain in a bit detail. What do you mean by reverse scaling here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is how I calculate my X and Y scaling factors :- 
float xFactor = self.frame.size.width/imageView.image.size.width;
float yFactor = self.frame.size.height/imageView.image.size.height;

Comment: Maybe you are setting the cropped image back in the cropView and forgot to set AspectFit on the cropView as well?